# Parsing Json to render multiline highstock charts using Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, json, highcharts

I m trying to parse a similar JSON output from a R Dataframe to render as a multiline highstock charts. I am new to javascripting and highcharts so having read the documentation for highstocks I am still at a loss to render the graph as I would like it to be.

I have the output from a R dataframe the JSON file of the form, (a sample) -

```
[[
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/1/2017",
   "Hits": 455
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/2/2017",
   "Hits": 457
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/3/2017",
   "Hits": 658
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/4/2017",
   "Hits": 645
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/5/2017",
   "Hits": 578
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/6/2017",
   "Hits": 425
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/7/2017",
   "Hits": 487
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/8/2017",
   "Hits": 499
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/9/2017",
   "Hits": 600
 },
 {
   "Server": "AAAA",
   "Date": "9/10/2017",
   "Hits": 567
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/1/2017",
   "Hits": 486
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/2/2017",
   "Hits": 595
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/3/2017",
   "Hits": 509
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/4/2017",
   "Hits": 460
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/5/2017",
   "Hits": 351
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/6/2017",
   "Hits": 488
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/7/2017",
   "Hits": 693
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/8/2017",
   "Hits": 478
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/9/2017",
   "Hits": 662
 },
 {
   "Server": "BBBB",
   "Date": "9/10/2017",
   "Hits": 401
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/1/2017",
   "Hits": 477
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/2/2017",
   "Hits": 474
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/3/2017",
   "Hits": 396
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/4/2017",
   "Hits": 372
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/5/2017",
   "Hits": 398
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/6/2017",
   "Hits": 605
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/7/2017",
   "Hits": 415
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/8/2017",
   "Hits": 522
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/9/2017",
   "Hits": 385
 },
 {
   "Server": "CCCC",
   "Date": "9/10/2017",
   "Hits": 378
 }
]]
```

The Javascript code I tried is shown below. Tried to group the json by Server so it is of the form required for highstock charts. [["name": "AAAA", "data": [[9/1/2017,455],[9/2/2017,457]...],"name": "BBBB, "data": [[9/1/2017,486],...]...]]

```js
var result = [];

/**
 * Create the chart when all data is loaded
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function createChart() {

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent',
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: true
        },

        series: result
    });
}

$.getJSON('data.json',    function (data) {
        result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.Server] = r[a.Server] || [];
        r[a.Server].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
        };

            createChart();

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

By using console.log() the json is being group but still the chart doesnt seem to be generating. Have spent over three days reading through SO .. trying various tips but still cant seem to figure out. Anyone able to point me in the right direction as to how to read the json, parse it in so that highstocks render would be great !!! Used the template found at https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare to generate the plot similar to this. The data set is dynamically filtered so cannot prepopulate the names field as the demo code found at highcharts. Also the date is generated as UNIX time.

Comment: x data (dates) needs to be given in milliseconds since 1970. You can use `new Date('your date here').getTIme()` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple example how to create Highstock chart with multiple series based on your JSON data:

```
function createChart(series) {
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        series: series
    });
}

$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d5580', function(data) {
    var series = [],
        name,
        newData = [];

    Highcharts.each(data[0], function(el, i) {
        if (!name) {
            name = el.Server;
        }
        if (name === el.Server) {
            newData.push({
                x: Number(moment(el.Date).format('X')),
                y: el.Hits
            });
        } else {
            series.push({
                name: name,
                data: newData
            });
            name = el.Sever;
            newData = [];
            newData.push({
                x: Number(moment(el.Date).format('X')),
                y: el.Hits
            });
        }
    });
    series.push({
        name: name,
        data: newData
    });
    createChart(series);
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qrxszc0b/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro

Comment: Thank you!!! worked like a charm. I had over 100000 data points so had to set the turboThreshold in plotOptions to 0 to disable checking.

Comment: Quick Question, my json doesnt parse when I dont have the double [[ at the beginning or end. It only works with the [[ ... ]]. My json output from the server is of the form [{}{}]. I have to manually change the json to [[{}{}{}]] for this to work. Can I do without [[{}{}]] and use only [{}{}]. When I load it as is, it doesnt render. Thanks for any pointers!!

Comment: You only need to change 'data[0]' to 'data' in 'Highcharts.each' method.

Comment: Awesome !! .. I am getting to understand how exactly these work !! Thanks